# Use instances, or pass parameters: best way to optimize

Tags: javascript, optimization

- I updated this Question, beacuse my Fiddles were not saved well -

I'm building an app that contain a serie of similar operations with a form.
Instead of adding a lot of forms I chose to use a generic form and dynamically change the events on the buttons of the form.

My challenge is to make the code more generic, so I easily can add much more operations without multiplying the code. The complete non-generic code is in the Fiddle link, a part of that is placed here, under the link.
[refined Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oysterhoys/6g90r8zq/5/)

```
// sample 


function init() {
    operationA.addEventListener('mousedown', prepareA);
    operationB.addEventListener('mousedown', prepareB);
}


// Operation flow:
// Prepare >> Cancel or Process >> Execute
function prepareA() {
    if (isEventsRemoved) {
        showForm();
        ok.addEventListener('mousedown', processA);
        cancel.addEventListener('mousedown', cancelA);
        isEventsRemoved = false;
    } else {
        alert("Cancel other operation first");
    }
}

function cancelA() {
    hideForm();
    cleanUp(processA, cancelA);
}

function processA() {
    hideForm();
    cleanUp(processA, cancelA);
    if (input.value == "a") {
        executeA();
    } else {
        alert("No good, try operationA again.");
        cleanUp(processA, cancelA);
        prepareA();
    }
}

function executeA() {
    alert("Executing A");
}
```

Instead of repeating the same functions/methods for A, B, C etc..
I started with generic functions, passing parameters for A, B ,C etc.
But when I follow this line, I don't know how to glue it together, some kind of recursiveness starts to appears, see the generic Fiddle. Again only part of the code under the Fiddle link.
[Problem Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oysterhoys/0fddp6ec/10/)

```
// Set it up
function init() {
    operationA.addEventListener('mousedown', function(){ prepareAll(processA, cancelA)});
    operationB.addEventListener('mousedown', function(){ prepareAll(processB, cancelB)});
}


// Operation flow:
// Prepare >> Cancel or Process >> Execute

function prepareAll(processHandler, cancelHandler) {
    if (isEventsRemoved) {
        showForm();
        ok.addEventListener('mousedown', processHandler);
        cancel.addEventListener('mousedown', cancelHandler);
        isEventsRemoved = false;
    } else {
        alert("Cancel current operation first");
    }
}

function cancelAll(processHandler, cancelHandler) {
    hideForm();
    cleanUp(processHandler, cancelHandler);
}
```

My question :  Is this way really a dead end and should I for example use object instances instead of using generic functions with parameters, or am I just not following the way in the right manner ?

Comment: Why do you use `mousedown` instead of `onclick`? Or, in the case of your first snippet, even together with `onclick`?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "dead end", why do you think so? [You had a typo, btw](https://jsfiddle.net/58mcf6ho/6/)

Comment: That www.quirksmode.org guru mentioned that the mousedown is saver. I  used the `= onclick` only for making a quick Fiddle.

Comment: Unlikely, `click` works for everything (that you like in this use case). You definitely shouldn't use both.

Comment: - I updated this Question, beacuse my Fiddles were not saved well -

Comment: Normally I would not mix them

Comment: If you want us to help you make your code more abstract, you're gonna have to make your question _less_ abstract. It makes no sense to me at the moment, no idea what you want to achieve exactly. Please describe your problem and perhaps the original code before you made an attempt to generalize it.

Comment: @ MDeSchaepmeester . You are right. Originally I had the non-generic code in my first Fiddle link, and links to an advancement version and to the problematic one. But at saving I got a message I could only add two links in my question. I chose to keep the last two. Now I have in the first link the simple code, where I have different sets of  function for every operation. In the second I have the generic version and I put a remark in that code till which point I succeeded in making it more generic. And at what point I got stuck.